# Sort array of structs by string

Tags: c, sorting, structure

I have this structure:

```
struct agente {
    int iCode;
    char cName[21];
    char cLName[21];
    char cAgentID[16];
    char cAssets[5][35];
    int iContAssets;
    int iAge;
    char cGender;
    char cMission[5][13];
    int iContMisiones;
};

typedef struct agente agente;
```

and I'm trying to sort an array of that structure by cName, using this function:

```
void sortAgents(agente* agentesArr, int iCantAgentes) {
    int didSwap = 0;
    agente temp;

    do {
        didSwap = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < iCantAgentes - 1; i++) {
            int comp = strcmp(agentesArr[i].cName, agentesArr[i+1].cName);
            if(comp > 0 ) {
                temp = agentesArr[i];
                agentesArr[i] = agentesArr[i+1];
                agentesArr[i+1] = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
            }
        }
    } while(didSwap == 1);
}
```

where iCantAgentes is amount of agents on the array, and agentesArr is the array.
For some reason, it's not working. Can someone help me identify the problem please?

Comment: "It's not working" doesn't tell us anything useful.  How do you know it's not working?  The function as given should work properly.  The problem is probably in the code you didn't show.  So please update your question with a [mcve] that others can run to reproduce the problem, including input, expected output, and actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function only sorts adjacent strings, not the whole array. Try this:

```
void sortAgents(agente* agentesArr, int iCantAgentes) {
    agente temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < iCantAgentes - 1; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j < iCantAgentes - 1; j++){
            int comp = strcmp(agentesArr[i].cName, agentesArr[j].cName);
            if(comp > 0) {
                temp = agentesArr[i];
                agentesArr[i] = agentesArr[j];
                agentesArr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```